# 504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I use a virtual machine to run my flask app 'sqtf'. She works on local using 127.0.0.1:5000, but not with my apache server. I use python3.6, apache2.4 and mod_wsgi.
this is a simplified structure of my project:

```
/var/www/squashPy/src/squash_test_filter/
                              /sqtf
                                  sqtf.wsgi
                                  __init__.py
                                  /static
                                  /templates
                              /venv
```

After configuring my VirtualHost 'sqtf.com.conf' on apache and then my sqtf.wsgi (configuring also my virtualenv and /etc/hosts), the server respond at www.sqtf.com but in my login page or any other, 'www.sqtf.com/auth/login' 504 Gateway Timeout Server  port 80.

In my error.log :

Timeout when reading response from deamon process 'sqtf': /var/www/squashPy/src/squash_test_filter/sqtf/sqtf.wsgi

I added a python-home in my DeamonProcess. 
Increase Timeout doesn't change anything.

my sqtf.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.sqtf.com
     ServerAlias sqtf.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/squashPy/sqtf.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/squashPy/sqtf.com/logs/custom.log combined
     WSGIDaemonProcess sqtf python-home='var/www/squashPy/src/squash_test_filter/venv'
     WSGIProcessGroup sqtf
     WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/..../sqtf/sqtf.wsgi
     Alias /static/ /var/wwww/..../sqtf/static
     <Directory /var/www/..../static>
          Require all granted
     </Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

my sqtf.wsgi

```
    activate_this='/var/www/..../venv/bin/activate_this.py'
    with open(activate_this) as file_:
            exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
    import sys
    import logging
    sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/squashPy/src/squash_test_filter/")
    from sqtf import app as application
```

a part of my /etc/hosts :

```
    127.0.0.1 localhost
    127.0.1.1 ubuntu
    127.0.0.1 www.sqtf.com sqtf.com sqtf

    # etc ...
```

a part of my /sqtf/**init**.py

```
    import ...



    def create_app(test_config=None):
        # create and configure the app

        app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
        api = Api(app)

        app.config.from_mapping(
            SECRET_KEY='dev',
            DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'sqtf.sqlite'),
        )

        if test_config is None:
            # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
            app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
        else:
            # load the test config if passed in
            app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

        # ensure the instance folder exists
        try:
            os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
        except OSError:
            pass
        db.init_app(app)
        return app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem, if you use a flask factory, with create_app for example, you need to change this line `from sqtf import app as application` in your .wsgi by this :

```
from sqtf import create_app
application=create_app()
```